# Android: how to highlight the title(as if it is selected) of the next tab in tab layout after navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have created a sign-up form with tab layout which includes three tabs(three fragments).  I have successfully ended up in navigating to the next fragment after clicking on 'Next' in my previous fragment. However my problem is that I am unable to highlight my current tab, which should be highlighted(as if it is selected) when I click 'Next' in my previous fragment.

The following is my first fragment(Account info):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                emailid = email.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidEmail(emailid)) {
                    email.setError("Invalid Email");
                }

                pass = password.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    password.setError("Password cannot be empty");
                }
                confirmPass = confirmPassword.getText().toString();
                if (!isValidPassword(confirmPass)) {
                    confirmPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
                }
```

I am navigating to the next fragment using the below code, could anyone suggest how to highlight the title of the next tab(fragment) after navigating to it?

```
                if (isValidEmail(emailid) && isValidPassword(pass)) {
                    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
    }
```

below is my activity code, how do i disable touch or click events on tabs?

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Account Info"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Personal Info"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Confirmation"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }
            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tabLayout.tabP(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this approach you have to implement this method

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener
```

and in `onPageSelected` method you have to re-write the tab name as per condition

you can implement a method like this

```
 private void initTabsName() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.subcat_custom_tab, tabLayout, false);
      // do something to make tab selected using if else statements
        /* // for example
           if (i == 0) {

            }
         */
        tab.setCustomView(relativeLayout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying your scenario, will let you know if i succeed.  I have another doubt, how do i disable manual touch or click on the tabs?

Comment: okk then you have to remove **tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);** from your activity

Comment: if it help you upto some extent please upvote and accept it as answer

Comment: @ThillaiK if your question will lead SO user's to do some research on the topic then you will surely get upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code solved my question:

```
if (isValidEmail(emailid) && isValidPassword(pass)) {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
}
```

I have initiated my `tabLayout` if my condition is true and called the method `getTabAt()` which is responsible to highlight the tabs in a Tab Layout. I have literally specified the tab position "1"(not 0, since 0 is still the first tab) in `getTabAt(1)` which I required to highlight under successful condition.

Comment: you can't post answer to your own post like this and accept it as answer for some points. otherwise you may get some penalty for this

Comment: Got it. sorry. Ill make a note.

Comment: in such conditions you can make edit to the post and bold the edit part

Comment: @RahulKhurana It's perfectly fine (encouraged, in fact) to provide an answer to your own question if you've figured out the solution. Thillai K, it would be helpful to others if you could give an explanation for your how this code solved your issue.

Comment: @thanksd  Obliged. I have edited my answer to give code explanation.  I hope I gave the best explanation.  Pardon me, if I have missed anything at all.